# Battery percentage shown in lockscreen while charging is incorrect

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, calibration

I have a Samsung Galaxy S-III (rooted & running 4.4.4) with a peculiar problem.

According to the Notification Bar toggles, the battery percentage is 82%. The same is shown in  `Settings > Battery`.

However, when I plug it in for charging, it shows "Charging, 49%".
After some time on the power, when the actual percentage was 99%, the lockscreen showed 69%. According to the custom Kernel, the battery percentage in the notification bar and settings is correct. Therefore, it must be something to do with the lockscreen widget.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Things I have tried:

- Reboot
- Factory Reset and Wipe Caches
- Reverting to Stock ROM

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your custom ROM. I've had such ROM showing incorrect percentage. Backup this image & try another ROM.

Comment: I've been using this stable ROM for over 6 months now. If it was a bug in the ROM, it should've showed up right away.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I never knew why it happened but when I tried another ROM, it got solved.

Comment: Issue persists on stock ROM.